# Creating Rhombus makes text italic

Tags: css, css-shapes

I wanted to create a Rhombus shape around text in CSS. I've got the shape working however, the text in the shape is now always italic.

I've tried to set `font-weight: normal` but it isn't changing anything.

My current code is:

```
<span id="shape_background">
    Test text
</span>

#shape_background { 
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
    background-color: red; 
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg); 
    transform: skew(-20deg); 
}
```

Comment: make the text a <p> or <span> element, and rotate that element back 20deg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to prevent the text getting the skew effect:

1. Wrap the text inside an element.
2. Apply inverse skew to the child
   element i.e. `skew(20deg)`, `+ve` value of 20deg to negate the effect of `-20deg`

```css
#shape_background {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
#shape_background .text {
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  transform: skew(20deg);
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="shape_background">
  <p class="text">Test text</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
#shape_background {
  display: block;
  //position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
#shape_background span {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  transform: skew(20deg);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<span id="shape_background">
    <span>Test text</span>
</span>
```